# How can we configure default imports in jupyter lab I have done this in jupyter notebook alone and it worked, but failing inside jupyter lab notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

image1: [image]

the above image1 is from jupyter notebook. And I got default imports as well.
I am expecting the same from jupyter lab notebook. Please ref second image.
Note: I tried jupyter lab extensions but I didn't get what I am looking for, I'm open for suggestions through jupyter lab extension also. Appreciate your help. thank you.

image2: [image]